# Active Directory Web Services update will not get installed when it should

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-update

I'm attempting to install Active Directory Web Services on a Windows 2008 64-bit server (No, not R2). I'm getting the download from the Microsoft download centre here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2852

Namely, it's Windows6.0-KB968934-x64.msu

I've tried the one that the manual says I should, but get the message

> The update does not apply to your system

When it definitely should! I've also tried the other packages available but, unsurprisingly, they didn't work either. Does anybody know what I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered this exact situation on a non-R2 server before.

It turns out that the hotfix you are trying to install is dependant on another hotfix - poorly documented.

I simply installed [`KB969166`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969166) and that got it working :)

Comment: I've installed that update but still getting the same message. I haven't rebooted yet though and it's a live server so will have to wait. Keep you informed (:

Comment: It seems .Net 3.5 SP1 is a prereq for this one